# How to quickly load approximately 1 million rows of data in a form?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a little c# **winforms** application that is connected to a **sql server** database.

We are using the [RadGridView](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/recording-tests/translators/silverlight-wpf-for-xaml/radgridview.aspx) (tabbed) control to display data from approximately 10 different views that are stored in sql server.

We have a thread running for each view (Tab) grabbing the data and populating each radgridview tab.

Our problem is this is taking way too long to load.

**How do we speed up the data retrieval?**

Here's what the control looks like:
[image]

Comment: Limit the results. Nobody is going to look through 1 million rows manually.

Comment: 1,000,000 and quickly don't live in the same planet :-)

Comment: Do you need to load so much data? If you do, have you considered paging?

Comment: The link you gave is for the WPF version of the grid. Are you sure you are using Winforms?

Comment: @xanatos sorry it is indeed a winform

Comment: [winforms doesn't support big data](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA). Use WPF.

Comment: @HighCore what technique would you use in WPF that is different than winform to load lots of data?

Comment: WPF has built in support for UI virtualization. You don't need to do anything. Anyways loading 1m records will take time, just to retrieve them from the DB and stuff like that. You should still Limit The results like @Elias said.

Comment: My advice is to quickly delete this question.

Comment: what do you guys think of this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: This was a friendly advice @АртёмЦарионов!

Comment: @xanatos not necessarily true. with ssms i'm able to select 1m rows in approx 20 sec

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Fortunately google doesn't let me wait 20 seconds for a search :-) 20 seconds on a free database on the best of days is *slow as hell*

Comment: @xanatos then it's my fault for throwing around the non descript word "quickly"

Answer (score 5):

You cannot load 1,000,000 rows quickly, because that's a lot of data to get from the RDBMS's disk through the network into the memory of your application. However, it does not mean that your application is bound to be slow: as long as you give end-users a perception that the data is there as soon as they are ready to see it, they would consider your application very fast.

The users would think that you loaded the data quickly if you load the data for the top few thousand rows on the initial page first, then load the remaining data for the initial page, and only then start loading the data for other tabs.

As you go tab-by-tab in the background, load only the top hundred rows in each tab, so that when end-users click the tab, they see that the data is there. Your code should load the rest of the data only when the user opens the tab: chances are, they never will open some of the tabs, helping your application save both on the processing and on the data transfer.

Comment: thank you very much. great answer. could you point me to some resources for this?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов There's very little that you need to know to implement this: to limit the number of rows coming back from sql server, add `TOP 1000` to the query. You may need to use data reader instead of binding to a table in order to add the limit ([link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-binding-to-datareader.html)). You may need to play around with various events of `RadGridView` to start the full load when the partial load has finished, or when the end-user switches to a different tab. I am not familiar with telerik to be more precise on this one, though.